# Django - Extract from JSON data using Python

Tags: python, json, django

Everytime I extract from JSON data, I will got `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`

My json info

```
u 'paging': {
    u 'cursors': {
        u 'after': u 'MTQyNzMzMjE3MDgxNzUzOQZDZD', u 'before': u 'OTUzNDg3MjMxMzQ2NjQ0'
    }
}, u 'data': [{
    u 'access_token': u 'XXXXX',
        u 'category': u 'Internet/Software', u 'perms': [u 'ADMINISTER',
            u 'EDIT_PROFILE', u 'CREATE_CONTENT', u 'MODERATE_CONTENT',
            u 'CREATE_ADS', u 'BASIC_ADMIN'
        ], u 'name': u 'Nurdin Norazan Services', u 'id': u '953487231346644'
}, {
    u 'access_token': u 'XXXXX',
        u 'category': u 'Internet/Software', u 'perms': [u 'ADMINISTER',
            u 'EDIT_PROFILE', u 'CREATE_CONTENT', u 'MODERATE_CONTENT',
            u 'CREATE_ADS', u 'BASIC_ADMIN'
        ], u 'name': u 'Intellij System Solution Sdn. Bhd.', u 'id': u '433616770180650'
}]
}
```

My code

```
data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/me/accounts?access_token="XXXXX")
print (data[data][0][id]) //953487231346644
```

Incidentally, how to print loop data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got the answer

```
data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/me/accounts?access_token="XXXXX")
for i in data['data']:
        print i['id']
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not in "extracting" the data: it's your print statement, as the full traceback would have shown.

In that statement for some reason you call `data[data]`. But that just means you're trying to index the data dictionary with itself. To get the data *key*, you need to use a string: `data["data"]`; and the same for the id value.

```
print(data["data"][0]["id"])
```

Comment: how to print in loop?

Comment: With a `for` loop?

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, `json.load` is for reading file pointers (or some object that implements the `read()` interface).
https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html#json.load

I'd say you want `json.loads`, but in fact you want `json.dumps`. Your TypeError implies that you are getting in a python dictionary (very similar to JSON), whereas json.load/s expects a string.

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps({"foo": "bar"})
'{"foo": "bar"}'
>>> json.loads({"foo": "bar"})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 312, in loads
    s.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'dict'
>>> json.loads(json.dumps({"foo": "bar"}))
{'foo': 'bar'}
```

As for looping through data, iterate through it:

```
for key, val in data.items():
    print("{}: {}".format(key, val))
```

You may have to implement some fancier looping if you want to recursively loop through json.